# Programmatic way to temporarily block specific Web Sites?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-xp, cross-browser

I need a way to programaticaly block and then later unblock specific websites based on their domain names.  I only need to block browsers (so http & https would be sufficient, I guess?) but not just Internet Explorer, it should also work for anyone trying to run Chrome or Firefox too.

This needs to work on Windows XP and be usable from a .NET program (Vb.net or C#).

(ps., I had found this question: [How to unblock website which is blocked, using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868054/how-to-unblock-website-which-is-blocked-using-c) which seems to be saying the same thing, however at the time I could not understand it.  Now I see it, thanks all.)
Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line in the hosts file will redirect to localhost.  Though I have nothing against Nascar ;)

```
127.0.0.1       www.nascar.com
```

[Block websites using a hosts file.](http://allthingsmarked.com/2006/08/28/howto-block-websites-using-the-hosts-file/)

Answer (score 1):

A down and dirty way would be to dynamically update the hosts file.

c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: OK, I have read the doc on the hosts file, but it does not say how to use it to block a site?

Answer (score 1):

You could add entries to the Hosts.ini file to achieve this. It would only work on Windows. Have a look here [link text](http://www.howtonetworking.com/whatis/hosts.htm)

Comment: OK, I have read the doc on the hosts file, but it does not say how to use it to block a site?

Answer (score 1):

First off, know that you need to be an Administrator to do this stuff.

Well, you can just add a line to the hosts file in ( c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts ) with the site you want, such as:

```
127.0.0.1 www.example.com
```

After that is done, just run the following command:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Some web browsers, including Firefox, will also have to be restarted as well.

To unblock a blocked site, just delete it's entry from the hosts file, or place a # sign at the beginning of it.